# local mem on opencl hardware

Tags: c++, c, cuda, opencl

I've been wondering, is there a way to estimate the mount of shared mem on the different GPGPU's without going out and buying the cards?

I currently have a GTS 330M with 16K shared mem in my laptop 
and a GTX 480 with 16K + 32K = 48K shared mem.

I would like to know if getting a tesla card would give me more shared mem pr block of if it would be the same as the GTX card.

How does one figure this out? I'm not able to look it up in the specs on nvidia's site ... perhaps a AMD GPGPU would be better, how does one figure this out?

I hope someone can help

Comment: Get an Amazon EC2 Cluster GPU instance ($2.10/hour for a pair of Tesla M2050s) and run a test program on that to determine how they perform, and whether they're worth purchasing. Estimating the relative performance of AMD and NVidia GPUs is very difficult, because their architectures are very different in a lot of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For NVIDIA hardware, the shared memory configuration of every CUDA/OpenCL capable card is described in Appendix F of the CUDA 4.0 programming guide.

To answer your question about a Ferm Telsa card, it has the same shared memory configuration as your GTX 480 - 16kb or 48kb of shared memory, user selectable at runtime.

Comment: All NVIDIA GPUs with the same compute capability have the same amount of shared memory per SM.  Currently that means CC >= 2.0 == 48KB.  CC < 2.0 == 16KB.

Answer (score 2):

As the data needs to be transferred over the PCI-e bus, the global memory on another device is as slow as using the memory of the CPU. If your input-data cannot be split up and therefore memory is a bigger bottle-neck than speed, try to use OpenCL on a vector-enabled CPU like Intel SandyBridge or AMD Fusion.

Comment: For the purpose I'm looking at I'm able to generate the data on the Gpu using only a very little initial data. So the problem of the bus bottle-neck should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Run the JavaCL hardware report, http://nativelibs4java.sourceforge.net/webstart/OpenCL/HardwareReport.jnlp ?

Comment: -1 whatever that is it doesn't run on standard osx, Also this looks like it only insects the hardware that I already have?

Comment: You probably need to install the Apple JDK/JRE :(

Comment: I wanted to correct this statement and point out that the JavaCL Hardware Report works on Macs (as of January 2012). However, on MacBook's you need to make sure you're using discrete video card or it will crash. Also, it requires you to have the card to see what it supports, something the author was trying to avoid.